# why is there a delay when recording my second track ? they dont align

Tags: audacity

I would like to figure out why my second tracks hold a delay from the first track instead of being completely aligned??

when i record shouldnt the singing be aligned with the music without me ajusting it????

Answer (score 5):

No.  You have a systemic delay.  When your recording software sends samples to the soundcard, they are buffered in the driver, sent to the card, buffered in the card, digitally filtered for oversampling (which also incurs a delay), buffered in the D/A converter and finally sent out.  Then you hear this already delayed signal, add your new voice to it, it gets received by the microphone, sampled by an A/D converter with oversampling, digitally filtered (incurring a delay), downsampled and buffered in the card, sent to the computer, buffered in the driver.  All of this delay both for playback and recording adds up to your systemic delay.  It can be measured by "short-circuiting" sound output and sound input and measuring the delay with which recognizable signals arrive.

Digital Audio Workstations like Ardour will offer to measure the systemic delay and compensate for it when recording.  And `jackd` will actually provide this information to applications when called with the proper options (`-I` and `-O` options).

I don't know Audacity well enough in order to tell whether you are just missing on configuring some option here.

But every recording solution will generate this systemic playback+record delay when recording new tracks to existing ones and needs to compensate for it.

Answer (score 2):

The [audacity manual](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/latency_test.html) explains how to measure latency and to set it in the "Edit/Preferences/Devices/Latency compensation" Tab/field (as compensation, it will be a negative value).